# How to connect to mysql server using database navigator plugin intelliJ

Tags: java, mysql, database, intellij-idea, server

This is my first time creating an application using my own mysql server and I can't figure out how to connect to it from intelliJ. I'm using the database navigator plugin and I keep getting the same error as seen in the picture. My username/password are 100% correct. But I'm not sure why the connection isn't being made.

I have attached a screenshot of the error. Thanks.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiH3F.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change host from localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: ya im on the mysql workbench and it says everything is up and running

Comment: the developer just put out an update and it fixed my issue lol, thx for trying

Comment: Ah, that explains it. I had just installed mine so I already had that fix.